# Artifactory Copy command through CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have recently started working in Artifactory (4.4.0). I have successfully configured artifactory cli to upload & download binaries from Artifactory by command line.

```
jfrog rt dl XXX/*.zip
```

But When I try to perform copy and move operations, I'm facing below.

```
jfrog rt cp XXX/* YYYY/ --login=** --password=***

Artifactory response: 400 Bad Request
```

When I do a dryrun, it works perfectly but in realtime, I'm getting the above ERROR.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the same command but use quotes like so:

```
jfrog rt cp "XXXX/*" YYYY/
```